# Pymongo LastRecord Sort Error

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to sort my records and get the last one to fetch my last insert ID.

```
cursor = collection.find().sort({'_id':-1}).limit(1)
```

Got this error.

```
TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list
```

I put it as a list like so,

```
cursor = collection.find().sort( [ {'_id':-1} ] ).limit(1)
```

And I got this error

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I tried running the same query on RoboMongo and it works. It just doesn't work on Pymongo in Python Script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a list of tuples to [`Cursor.sort`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.sort).

> **sort(key_or_list, direction=None)**
>
> Sorts this cursor’s results.
>
> Pass a field name and a direction, either ASCENDING or DESCENDING [[docs]](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.sort)

```
collection.find().sort([
    ('_id', pymongo.DESCENDING),
])
```

or arguments like so:

```
collection.find().sort('_id', pymongo.DESCENDING)
```